# Deploying to AppEngine, I get "too many files" error

Tags: google-app-engine

Following [this community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-ktor-app-engine-java8) for setting up ktor in GCP AppEngine, I additionally modified the 'webapp' folder to be a full react-based SPA. Running `npm start` in the webapp directory works fine, as does running `./gradlew appengineRun` in the outer directory. But when trying to deploy, it complains that I have >10k files. Without details, it seems the node_modules are most likely to blame.

Looking online for several hours, the old solution was to add a 'skipFiles' section to app.yaml, and the newer solution is to create a .gcloudignore file. In both, listing `node_modules` should cause them to not be deployed. But, with the tutorial I'm following, I don't have an app.yaml file - it's apparently being constructed from the various .xml configs as part of the staging step of the appEngine gradle plugin. I can create the .gcloudignore file, but it doesn't get pushed to the deploy staging folder (called 'build/staged-app'). Even manually placing it there, it doesn't build properly because then there is a skipFiles and .gcloudignore, which can't coexist.

I feel there is some 1 line change to make this work, but I have no idea what it might be. I've tried creating app.yaml files in the project with overridden settings, but the deploy step doesn't pick them up - it just always generates one from scratch it seems.

Any idea how I can get this to work? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an `app.yaml` file becuaseu you are using the [`App Engine Gradle Plugin`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/gradle-reference).

*EDIT*

It seems you have to follow [exclude syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#include_exclude) using `<exclude>` elements. In a pattern, `*` represents zero or more of any character in a file or dir name, and `**` represents zero or more dirs in a path. Files matching this element will not be uploaded when you deploy your AppEngine app.

An `<include>` element overrides the default behavior of including all files. An `<exclude>` element applies after all  patterns (as well as the default if no explicit `<include>` is provided).

The following example demonstrates how to designate all `.png` files as static files (except those in the `data/` directory and all of its subdirectories):

```
<static-files>
  <include path="/**.png" />
  <exclude path="/data/**.png" />
</static-files>
```

You can use this with your path `node_modules`